# FUNCTION IF TO COMPARE DATES

Tags: excel-formula

Good afternoon,
I am trying to compare that a date is equal to an exact value but despite being it returns a false. Do you have any solutions?

```vb
=IF(AI14=31/12/9999;TRUE;FALSE)
=IF(AI14="31/12/9999";TRUE;FALSE)
```

The value is in a pivot table, is a problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data and show us what you expect. Reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to enhance your question.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to comparing different types of data (string vs numeric which will therefore be unequal and return `FALSE`). Convert them to the same type & retry (i.e. numeric date == numeric date).

[image: Excel image for A1==A2 vs. B1==B2]

Comment: I'm trying to do what you've said this way, but keep returning false

Comment: =IF(AS14=ISNUMBER(31/12/9999);TRUE;FALSE)

Comment: ISNUMBER() will perform another TRUE/FALSE check. I think you need to convert them to the same type (e.g. remove the quotes that I am assuming are around the date in cell AS14). I will edit my comment to include a picture to help explain.

Comment: I have finally achieved it, thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: =IF(AS14=DATE(9999;12;31);TRUE;FALSE)

Comment: Great - feel free to upvote the answer if you think it helped solve your question! (Trying to build rep!)